# Аргумент метода, вызываемого из другого класса ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть код.

```
helper Add = new helper();
public ActionResult Books()
{
    var view = Add.Books(//сюда);
    return view;
}
```

Вызывается из класса

```
public class helper : Controller
{
    MySqlConnection sql;
    public ActionResult Books(string name)
    {
        name = "select * from " + name;
        sql = new MySqlConnection("Database=bookstoredatabase;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root");
        sql.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(name, sql);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            books.Add(new Book()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]),
                Author = Convert.ToString(reader["author"]),
                Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader["price"]),
                Genre = Convert.ToString(reader["genre"]),
                Language = Convert.ToString(reader["language"]),
                Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader["year"]),
                Cover = Convert.ToString(reader["cover"])
            });
        }
        ViewBag.Books = books;
        //
        return View();
    }
}
```

Тут метод принимает строку для sql запроса.
Что передать сюда?

```
public ActionResult Books()
{
    var view = Add.Books(//вот сюда);
    return view;
}
```

Пробовал передавать `string name` или просто имя строки, ругается на все.

Comment: все неправильно: 1. метод контроллера вызывается из другого контроллера, 2. непараметризованый SQL = SQL Injection, 3. connection не закрывается, 4. в `return View();` будет использован не то представление, которое имеется в виду. (проб**О**вал)

Comment: @Igor я тут помимо слов автора (_из друго**В**а_) не вижу, чтобы из одного контроллера вызывался другой. Хотя я вообще не понял, что такое `Add.Books()`.

Comment: я все понимаю что все криво.Add.Book(); Add это `helper Add = new helper();`  У меня возвращает все то что мне нужно.У меня только проблема с аргументом который надо передать

Comment: а зачем `helper` контроллер?

Comment: `helper` это не контролер а  добавленый класс  наследованый от `Controller` в котором  я возвращаю `View`  в главный контролер и потом отображаю

Comment: просто так сделано не знаю почему

Comment: пардон, это Ваш код?

Comment: да я сам все с нуля делал

Comment: начните с простого, когда весь код в контроллере, и никаких хелперов нет

Comment: У меня поначалу так и было но я захотел попробывать так и все работает как и работало ранее пока не запнулся на этом моменте.

Comment: покажите, как было раньше (попроб**О**вать)

Comment: `namespace BookStore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        helper Add = new helper();
        MySqlConnection sql;

        public ActionResult Books()
        {   // тут код из метода  Book который выше
            public ActionResult Books(string name){ }
            return View;
        }
     }
} `вот и все как бы поэтому

Comment: у меня все работало но сейчас я вызываю метод из подключеного класса то вылазит ошибка про аргумент который надо передать в` public ActionResult Books()
            {
                var view = Add.Books(//вот сюда);
                return view;
            }`

Comment: так, и откуда бралось название таблицы в старом коде?

Comment: вот так @Ajax.ActionLink((string)genre.Name, "Books", new { name = @genre.Name },new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "book_news"})

Comment: Как выглядела строчка `"select * from ...` в старом коде?

Comment: `"select * from " + name;` name это передавая строка в метод Book все осталось как было я просто перенес все в новый класс helper и из него вызываю метод и все.

Comment: Последний вопрос - откуда бралась переменная `name` в `"select * from " + name` в старом коде?

Comment: у выходит так.Есть жанры книг.Каждый жанр это таблица в БД и я помощ foreach генерирую <li></li> список `@foreach (var genre in ViewBag.Genres)
            {
                <li>
                   @Ajax.ActionLink((string)genre.Name, "Books", new { name = @genre.Name },new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "book_news"})
                </li>
         }` и при нажатии на него идет запрос на метод Book  и загружается список книг из базы.загрузка книг делается через модель`public class Genre
    {
        //жанры
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }` где в Book передается имя жанра

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Books(string name)
{
  var view = Add.Books(name);
  return view;
}
```

Comment: спасибо работает! я просто я не думал что в это метод тоже надо передавать что потому что